# Что происходит в этой строке?: xor ^= A[i];

Tags: java, массивы, for, int

Что происходит в этой строке?: `xor ^= A[i];`

Весь код:

```
public class FindOdd {
    public static int findIt(int[] A) {
        int xor = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) {
            xor ^= A[i];
            System.out.println(xor);
        }
        return xor;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` — это побитовый оператор исключающее "или"

В данном случае, к `xor` применяется `^`, который копирует бит, если он установлен в одном из операндов, но не в обоих.

Допустим есть:

```
xor = 0011 1100
A[i] = 0000 1101
```

Соответственно `xor ^= A[i] // xor = 0011 0001`

Чтобы визуально проще было:

```
0011 1100 // xor 
0000 1101 // A[i]
0011 0001 // xor ^= A[i]
```

Comment: Премного благодарен)